# User and group permissions in access.conf

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

How do I configure access.conf so that the following rule is applied? :

Allow the user dia to connect from 192.152.100.
Deny the user sim to connect from 192.152.100.
Particularity : both the users dia (uid = 8389753) and sim (uid = 500) belong to the group sim (gid = 500)
Yes, the user and group sim have the same name and the same id.

With the follwing syntax,

```
- : sim : 192.152.100.
```

the user sim is denied, as well as dia (because dia belongs to the group sim). access.conf considers sim as being both the user and group.

How do I specify that I want to deny the user sim, but at the same time allow the user dia ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet:

```
+ : dia : 192.152.100.
- : sim : 192.152.100.
```

It's working fine on my CentOS.